# Is voters motive on topic?

Tags: discussion

What's actually on Bush' mind when he attacked Iraq is off topic because we don't know what's on Bush's mind.

However, what about voters' or large "typical" humans want? Is that off topic? Humans' nature is part of science right?

For example, the left claim that pro life are simply anti choice. They just want things to go really wrong when someone have sex outside marriage. The right may counter claim that pro choice are simply murderous people that love to kill babies.

I think they're both right. Can I ask that?

Comment: I'm both impressed and sad for you that you are agreeing with two sides supposedly throwing out ad-hominens. Both of those arguments are phrased that way to instill anger and kill a discussion, not to have a reasoned debate on the issue at hand.

Comment: **[Married women have abortions too](http://www.guttmacher.org/pubs/fb_induced_abortion.html)**

Comment: Meta is not a platform for you to present your theories, it is meant for discussing this site, not for anything else. I've rolled back your edits to remove all that stuff.

Comment: You mean voters motive are not testable? you can't check their consistency with their other action? If somebody stab your son and claim he's doing it to operate apendix no body can know it's not true?

Answer (score 4):

Ask yourself: "How could a possible test for this claim look like"?

> The right may counter claim that pro choice are simply murderous people that love to kill babies.

What kind of evidence would exist that you think that this claim is wrong? What evidence could exist to show that this claim is right?

At the moment I can't think of a test that you could run to see whether this claim is true.
It's therefore a bad question for this website.

You could however reword the question:
"Are people who are pro choice more likely commit murder according to the current legal definition of murder"? (the claim that they are murderous people)
"Do people who are pro choice feel pleasure when there an abortion?" (they love to kill babies)

The trick is to make your claim specific. If there a clear test that you could run to see whether the claim is true than it's okay.

Comment: +1, with the caveat that "pro-choice people commit more (non-abortion-related) murder" isn't a notable claim that I have ever heard.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Yes, notability is a second issue. I think that you could find some fundamentalist that makes such claims I you search hard enough. It should be a byproduct of the "If you don't believe in God, you have no basis for morals"-debate.

Answer (score 0):

It is off topic because 100 people could vote the same way for 100 different reasons. A vote means nothing more than that the largest number of people thought that the selected choice was the better one.

Politicians spin election results because there is really no way to prove them wrong.  They can go out and ask a poll slanted precisely so that they can get the answer they want.  If the poll comes back badly they bury it and try again.  You can be skeptical of the polls.  But not of a collection of people motives because they can all be different.